# Prove $f(c) = c$ under a condition.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, nonstandard-analysis

> Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f(0) = 1, f(1) = 0$. Prove that there is a point $c$ in $(0, 1)$ such that $f(c) = c$.

---

let $l(x) = x$ and $d(x) = f(x) - l(x)$.

We have $d(1) = f(1) - l(1) = -1$ and
$d(0) = 1$.

We divide $[-1, 1]$ in $H$ equal parts , where $H$ is a infinite hyperinterger.

$$-1, -1 + \delta, -1 + 2\delta, \ ... \  , -1 + H\delta = 1$$

Let $-1 + K\delta$ be the last partition point such that $d^*(-1 + K\delta) < 0$

$$\therefore d^*(-1 + K\delta) < 0 < d^*(-1 + (K+1)\delta)$$

$$\therefore f^*(-1 + K\delta) < -1 + K\delta  < f^*(-1 + (K+1)\delta) - \delta$$

Since $f^*(-1 + K\delta) \approx  f^*(-1 + (K+1)\delta) - \delta$, therefore $f^*(-1 + K\delta) \approx -1 + K\delta$

Let $c = st(-1 + K\delta)$

By taking standard part of the $f^*(-1 + K\delta) \approx -1 + K\delta$ , we get $f(c) = c$.

---

- I think this is probably correct but to be on the safe side please check my proof.

Comment: Do you know the intermediate value theorem ?

Comment: @Adren Yes that is what I proved here for a special case I guess.

Comment: I think there is a simpler proof. Just draw the picture then everything will be clear. The only tool that you will need is the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @JackyChong Picture of what ?

Comment: A picture of $g(x)=x$ and your $f(x)$.

Comment: @JackyChong I can draw $g(x)$ but I don't have points for $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\st}{st}$This is indeed the correct and usual approach to proving the intermediate value theorem (and hence this question) under nonstandard analysis.

The fundamental idea is if $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and $u\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(a)<u<f(b)$ (or $f(b)<u<f(a)$) then there is a $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=u$. Why? $[a,b]$ has a finite subset $F$ containing its standard elements and therefore defining $x=\min\{x'\in F:u\leq f(x')\}$ gives $c=\st(x)$ provided $f$ was continuous. This is slightly more general than the idea you used where you provided a particular set $F$ (which in fact gives a simpler proof), but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Call $d(x)=f(x)-x$ then $d(0)=1$ and $d(1)=-1$, so by Bolzano's Theorem there is a number $c\in(0,1)$ such that $d(c)=0$.

Comment: I don't know Bolzano's theorem. :(. Is it similar to IVT ?

Comment: @A---B, see here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BolzanosTheorem.html

Comment: I think the point of the exercise was to use nonstandard analysis, not the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I also think so.

Comment: @UmbertoP Why is it the point of the exercise to use nonstandard analysis?  To me, this seem like a very standard problem using IVT.

Comment: One can certainly prove this without the intermediate value theorem but it seems to me that such a proof is merely a re-proof of the intermediate value theorem in disguise, so perhaps it is better to use the intermediate value theorem after all.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Is my proof correct ? I also think this is more or less IVT.

Comment: @JackyChong for starters, the OP did not ask how to solve the stated problem, he/she asked for comments on the solution which uses nonstandard analysis. Also the question is tagged "nonstandard-analysis"